# Qt problem when working over classes GUI access

Tags: c++, qt

I got 2 classes:
- MainWindow (Was the default class)
- ExtraClass (That i created myself)

Inside the class MainWindow i've made a public function called "logger". This function looks like this:

```
// Takes in a QString and appends it to a QTextEdit.
void MainWindow::logger(QString Log_MSG)
{
    ui->Logg->append(Log_MSG);
}
```

This logger functions works out as expected inside its own Class `MainWindow` but when i try to pass in a MSG into logger from the class `ExtraClas`s, it suddenly doesn't work.

My approach to accessing logger from `MainWindow` to `ExtraClass`:

```
MainWindow Con;
Con.logger("The Message the will get appended to ui->logg");
```

So the question, what have i missed? I don't get any errors and the text "Log_MSG" that should be appended to the `QTextEdit` Log don't execute.

- Sorry for the style, i just don't understand how to get it to look good.

EDIT:

I've already tried to access other functions from "MainWindow class"
and that works but when i try to pass a string this particuallry function "logger"
from another class nothing happens.

For an instance:

`MainWindow MainWindow;`

`int ANumber = MainWindow.GiveMeAValue(); // This works`

But when i'm doing this:

`MainWindow MainWindow;
MainWindow.logger("Log MSG"); // This dosen't work`

My guess is that the problem lies in the appendment of
a QString passed in into the main class that was automatically created by Qt (have stuff like ui->abc) from another class. But in my current
level of understandment of Qt i don't really know where to
troubleshoot beocuse i don't even get an error.

Comment: The text inputted doesn't get appended into ui->Logg from another class but inside the same class it get appended to it. Also, I've made the logger function public.

Answer (score 3):

Your code to access the logger is wrong (it shouldn't even compile).

First, everytime you call the function where this code resides, you create a new local `MainWindow` object (`Con`). And then you try to call the method on the class and not on an object. If it is a static method (which I doubt, due to the use of `ui`), you would have to write `MainWindow::logger()`. If it is not a static method, then you need to call it on a specific `MainWindow` instance. But instead of creating a local `MainWindow` everytime, you should provide the correct application's `MainWindow` instance to your `ExtraClass` object.

If all this sounds alien to you, you should first look a bit deeper into fundamental C++ programming before delving into Qt.

Comment: Sorry, i'm tired so i misstyped the structure on my first post. Have fixed it to:
MainWindow.logger();

Comment: @Alexander Ok, my answer still applies. Everytime you want to log you create a new local MainWindow. And don't name you variables the same like their class. This can only cause confusion and should actually cause errors (which in your case it seems to do).