# Qt: Executing append from another class

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm quite new to Qt and C++ in general so this might be a simple problem.

**Current problem:**

I want to execute a function that appends text to a TextEditField by calling the function from another class. I can call the function and the text gets appended via the same class but when i try calling it from another class it simply won't execute the append and gives no errors.

To make it simple i will just call my classes A and B.

```
Class A // The class that was created automatically by Qt 
Class B // A class that i made myself
```

**Class A** have a function called "logger" which looks like this:

```
void ClassA::logger()
{
    ui->Logg->append("A log message"); // Straight forward, it appends the text
}
```

I can call **ClassA::logger** from another function in Class A and everything works out great like this:

```
void ClassA::MakeALogg()
{
    logger(); // The logger function appends the text to TextEditField Logg
}
```

BUT, when i try to execute the logger function from another function it won't work. My current code looks like this in **ClassB**:

```
void ClassB::MakeALogg()
{
    ClassA A;
    A.logger(); // The text doesn't get appended to TextEditField Logg via external class
}
```

This won't work when calling the logger() function and no errors where given.

The end result is to make this being enabled to get a QString passed into the logger() function, something i all tough can do at this time if i call it via the same class e.g `ClassA::MakeALogg() to ClassA::logger(QString LogMSG)`. But i want to first make sure that i can access the ui-> function from another class.

**My Theory**

Well i guess that the problem lies in some form of miss instantiation for the class for this specific exection (e.g the Ui type). I can at this stage call a function from class A to Class B and rechive a return { `for example ClassA::GiveNumber() to ClassB::NumberCalculator()` }. But when it comes related to the Ui it can't make a connection for some strange reason.

I've also tried to in the header file of **ClassB** to make a relation to it but that didn't work either:

```
class ClassA;

class ClassB
{
public:
ClassA * PointToClassA;
}

Void ClassB::Logger()
{
PointToClassA = new ClassA;
ClassA->logger();
}
```

Comment: In your pseudocode there seems to be no problem. Could you do two things? First is toggling a breakpoint and then going step by step (it's in every decent IDE, like the excellent QtCreator)? The second point is : could you post your actual code, especially the `void ClassB::MakeALogg()` method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Qt problem when working over classes GUI access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311128/qt-problem-when-working-over-classes-gui-access)

Comment: So you didn't like the answer to your other question and also didn't want to wait some time for a better one? Ok, in this case you just have to repost the exact same question ;)

Answer (score 1):

On both your methods, you are creating a new `ClassA` object, you would see the problem if you called `show` on the local variable:

```
void ClassB::MakeALogg()
{
    ClassA A;
    A.show();
    A.logger(); 
}
```

So, you should be calling the `logger` method on the class instance that already exists, and to do so, you need either to:

- pass the pointer of `ClassA` to all the classes that need logging,
- use a static function of `ClassA` or a global function to route the call to that instance (some sort of "Singleton pattern"),
- emit a signal in `ClassB`, and connect it to a slot in `ClassA` that would do the logging (the signal/slot connection should be done in `ClassA`).

If there is only 2 classes, as it seems to be the case according to the example you gave with "ClassB::NumberCalculator" or if all the instances of the other classes are children of a unique instance of `ClassA`, the third solution is probably the best.

Answer (score 0):

Like in your other question. Everytime you call this function you create a completely new instance of class A. The function actually works, but you don't see anything, because right after the function returns you return from the class B method and the local object gets destroyed. You have to provide the B a pointer or reference to the real A object you want this function to be called on.